# Multiple contracts in one WCF service_But error for calling the second contract

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, soapui

I have multiple contracts in one WCF:

```
namespace SysLap.Services.Web.DataExtractor
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceDataExtractor
    {      
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        List<User> GetAllUsers(/*CommonParams commonParams*/);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IScopesExtract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        List<SyScope> GetAllScopes();
    }
}
```

and the Web.config is well configured:

```
 <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.DataExtractor.IServiceDataExtractor" />
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="SysLap.Services.Web.DataExtractor.IScopesExtract" />
  </service>
```

For the service GetAllUsers, it is worked very good. But for the service GetAllScopes, when i test it with SOAP UI, i am getting this error:

```
<p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
    <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Multiple filters matched.'.
        See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
    <p> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcherTable.LookupInCache(Message message, Boolean&amp;
        addressMatched)
        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcherTable.Lookup(Message message, Boolean&amp;
        addressMatched)
        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.GetDatagramChannel(Message message, EndpointDispatcher&amp;
        endpoint, Boolean&amp; addressMatched)
        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EnsureChannelAndEndpoint(RequestContext request)
        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryRetrievingInstanceContextCore(RequestContext request)
    </p>
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you convert the screenshot of text back into plain text? Makes it much easier for others searching for the same problem.

Comment: Yes of course ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use the WCF project template to create WCF service, normally there is only one service host in Service.svc(Markup).

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService3.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

It means that we could have multiple service contracts, but we merely can have one service(service implementation class).
Under this circumstance, hosting multiple service contracts in one project is valid.

```
public class Service1 : IService1,IService2
```

Back to your problem, the error mainly indicates that our services have the same relative address, this does not comply with the WCF addressing specification.
As [**Selim Yıldız**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226735/5519709) said, we need two separate endpoint address.

```
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="a" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="b" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService2" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
```

The service Url will be,

> http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc/a/GetAllUsers
>   http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc/b/GetAllScopes

Feel free to let me know If there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thanks for your replay, in fact i want that the twice have the same endpoint address
http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc/rest/GetAllUsers and
http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc/rest/GetAllScopes

In fact, I try with other solution: I create two different interfaces and two SVC : 
* ServiceScopes.svc and * DataExtractor.svc

and now it is well working..but it is normally to create different svc ? or it is OK , thanks

Comment: Adding different SVC can also result in different service base addresses. http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc     http://xxxx:xx/service2.svc    We'd better implement services in a single service contract so that we can achieve the purpose of the identical base address.

Comment: very clear! thanks a lot, I understand very well now

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need two separate endpoint `address`.

Change the config and give unique address, for example:

```
<endpoint address="DataExtractor" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.DataExtractor.IServiceDataExtractor" />
<endpoint address="ScopesExtractor" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.DataExtractor.IScopesExtract" />
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, in fact I want the same enpoint address,